# git merge replace or overwrite a branch

Tags: git

I don't know if `rebase` or `merge` strategies or anything here is what I need or want.

The scenario

```
dev---*
       \A------*------
                \A2---------
```

ultimatly, I could just merge `A2` into `dev`.  This is the end result, but, is there a way to merge `A2` back into `A` and basically replace or overwrite all the commits post `A2` branch?

Why?  As a teaching moment.  I would really like to be able to show the diff between the "head" of `A` vs `A2` via viewing the merge or `A2` into `A` (all merges are done as `--no-ff`)

**clarification:**
it would be nice to see my git history like this

```
dev---*                        /---
       \A------*------       -*
                \A2---------/
```

so, the "merge" commit on `A` when viewed in something like gitlab will show me the diff.

I am just being picky about how the GitLab repository "graph" will look, as well as the individual commit view.  The changes.

Maybe I'll just do some experimenting with merging.

**more clarification** new question.
considering this git history

```
dev---*
       \A------*++++++
                \A2---------
```

Can I merge `A2` into `A` completely overwriting all the `+` commits, but keep them in the history?

Comment: could you clarify your question. To see the diff between the branches you can just run `git diff A A2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@ChrisMaes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2082964/chris-maes) pointed out in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57476524/git-merge-replace-or-overwrite-a-branch#comment101425264_57476524), you can compare the total amount of changes that happened between the `A` and `A2` branches by simply running `git diff` between their [heads](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#Documentation/gitglossary.txt-aiddefheadahead).

For example:

```
git diff A A2
```

will give you the changes that `A2` were made in the `A2` branch compared with `A`, while:

```
git diff A2 A
```

will give you the opposite, that is the changes that were made in `A` as compared to `A2`.

The reason you can do this is because in Git each commit points to a *snapshot* of all the files in your project as they were at the time of the commit.

From the ["*Snapshots, Not Differences*"](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Getting-Started-Git-Basics#Snapshots,-Not-Differences) section of the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Getting-Started-Git-Basics#Snapshots,-Not-Differences):

> Git thinks of its data more like a set of snapshots of a mini filesystem. Every time you commit, or save the state of your project in Git, it basically takes a picture of what all your files look like at that moment and stores a reference to that snapshot.

This means that the snapshot referenced by the latest commit of a branch (aka. the [tip](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#Documentation/gitglossary.txt-aiddefheadahead)) contains the *cumulative set of changes* that happened in that branch―not just the differences between that commit and the previous one.

Comment: In the end, I used git diff to preview what the merge would look like.  I then just merged `A2` into `A` and spent some time "cleaning up".  Every file with a merge conflict was just checkout out directly into `A`

Answer (score 1):

If the only reason for doing this merge is to be able to view the difference explained in the last paragraph, I would suggest this:

`git diff $(git merge-base A A2) A2`

This will list all the diffs between the last mutual commit of `A` and `A2` and the tip of the branch `A2`.

**Edit:**
I've just [learned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25609305/7629206) that `git diff A...A2` is syntactic sugar for `git diff $(git merge-base A A2) A2`, ie. it gives all the changes introduced in branch `A2` since it diverged from `A`.

Answer (score 0):

First, find the commit where `A2` branched from `A`:

```
git merge-base A A2
```

This will give you the commit id. Then, if you don't mind losing your extra commits on `A`, reset `A` to that commit:

```
git checkout A
git reset --hard <commit id>
```

Then merge `A2` into `A`:

```
git checkout A
git merge A2
```

Then merge `A` into `dev`:

```
git checkout dev
git merge A
```

Note: Instead of performing a hard reset on `A`, you could do `git stash` or save the diff to a patchfile:

```
git diff <commit id> > patchfile.diff
```